# Is there any way to get(or set) unique id for each widget in your flutter app and reference it for later use?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Just like Javascript has `getElementById()` that allows you to reference and access each element in your page, is there any flutter dependency or dart equivalent that allows you to do it for a packaged app?
I'm setting up a platform that allows one to add app nudges without coding anything.
It consists of a web interface where the end user can decide what widget should get what type of nudge. This is done by listing all the widgets available on the app screen to the user on the web interface, and giving him/her options(like checkboxes) of what type of nudges to add. Now, I want that my app should get this data(of what widget should have what nudge) and accordingly modify the widgets(add animation/change color/etc) while the app is running.

**TLDR**: I need a `.getElementById()` and `.innerHTML()` equivalent for dart widgets.
Note: I looked into flutter keys, but they only work on lists(like ListViews, ListView.builder, etc). I need to uniquely identify **every** widget in my entire app using some identifier.

Answer (score -1):

in dart you can assign keys to widgets

for accessing text input boxex, etc we have controllers that we can assign to each widget

however for something simple like changing a color you can just create a color variable, assign it to the button, then change the value for the color variable on an event

```
    Color myColor = Colors.black;
    
    ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: myColor,
      ),
    )
    
    //event onclick, ect...change the button color
    
    myColor = Colors.white;

setState(() {
    //call set state to update ui
  });
```

Comment: No this isn't what I'm looking for.
I need the widgetID so one can uniquely reference and identify widgets for any widget.
So for example if I'm on a checkout screen and I get a particular widgetID(from a remote server) for one of many buttons on that screen, then I should be able to reference that specific button widget and make changes to it. Exactly like getDocumentById and innerHTML in JS, so I can access and modify it's properties.

Comment: In addition to this, keys are used for listviews, however I need a unique identifier for each widget in the entire app (regardless of whether the widget is in a listview or not).